# Пояснительная конструкция при однородных членах

Tags: двоеточие, сложное-предложение, бсп, пояснительная

*Связи вовне дают новые возможности и **свободу выбора**: кроме текущего места работы у тебя всегда есть другие варианты.*

Понятно ли здесь, что вторая часть бессоюзного предложения (либо пояснительная конструкция в форме целого предложения) поясняет лишь "свободу выбора", а не оба однородных члена или всю первую часть?

Решит ли проблему отделение поясняемого члена посредством присоединительного союза?

*Связи вовне дают новые возможности, а также **свободу выбора**: кроме текущего места работы у тебя всегда есть другие варианты.*

Comment: Неясно, какова цель такой борьбы. Вы хотите показать читателю, что не считаете наличие "других вариантов" возможностью? Почему это так Вам важно? Пусть читатель сам решит. Это никак не влияет на понимание текста.

Comment: А оборот с предлогом кроме не нужно выделить? (...кроме текущего места работы, у тебя всегда есть другие варианты).

Comment: @Людмила Насколько я знаю, в значении «дополнительно, вдобавок к чему-либо» запятая факультативна.

Comment: @М_Г Никакой борьбы нет, просто нужно показать, что часть предложения после двоеточия поясняет именно "свободу выбора".

Comment: Это была факультативна, а теперь по Лопатину обязательна, если стоит в начале предложения    http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=216

Comment: @Людмила Вы ведь говорите он обязательном выделении оборота "кроме текущего места работы", не так ли? Этого не было в вопросе, поэтому сразу не поймешь, о чем речь.

Comment: @ВасилийЕфименко , "Просто нужно показать", а я не возьму в толк, зачем это нужно показать, какой от этого прок, что это меняет.  Это какой-то схоластических вопрос: если у тебя есть другие варианты, то это называется только свободой выбора  или это можно также считать новыми возможностями.

Comment: @Людмила Лопатин авторитетнее Розенталя? Разъясните, на чьи правила сегодня ориентироваться?

Comment: @М_Г Вы же не знаете контекста, замысла автора. В вопросе поставлена чёткая синтаксическая задача. А какова её цель, основания — это уже другая тема, не относящаяся к вопросу.

Comment: @М_Г "Пусть читатель сам решит". К слову сказать, я не очень приветствую такой подход. В тексте должна быть однозначность и единообразие понимания читателем того, что хочет сообщить автор.

Comment: Василий Ефименко, дело не в авторитете, а в современности. Ориентироваться нам сегодня предлагают на новый  справочник  РАН " Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации" , а редакторы его как раз   В.Лопатин и Валгина. И расхождений с Розенталем там не так и много, нужно этот перечень изменений иметь под рукой, и всё будет нормально.